# Upgrading from platform.js to webcomponents.js issue

Tags: polymer

I have just updated my polymer project ( bower update ) to switch to the new webcomponents.js library.
However I get a:
"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" on polymer.js:12

This is my index.html page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Nautes Dashboard</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->

    <!-- build:css styles/main.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    <!-- endbuild-->

    <!-- Place your HTML imports here -->
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="elements/elements.html">

</head>
<body>

    <nautes-pass-dashboard>
    </nautes-pass-dashboard>

  <script>
    document.addEventListener('polymer-ready', function() {
        // Perform some behaviour
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

I have to switch back to the old import to make all work again:

```
<script src="bower_components/platform/platform.js"></script>
```

Did I do something wrong updating my project?

Comment: Did you try updating Polymer to 0.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still used `platform.js` I guess you used an old version of Polymer.
My guess is that when you update to `webcomponents.js`, your kept the old version of  Polymer, that isn't compatible with the `webcomponents.js`.

If my guess is right, you need to update all your Polymer setting, not only change `platform.js` with `webcomponents.js`. Take version 0.5.5 of Polymer and it should work better.

Comment: thank you so much, indeed was a problem with the polymer version in my project. Doing bower update didn't upgraded the version of polymer installed. Now it's all working! :)